# Esc [2J how to achieve this in Java?

Tags: java, escaping

Note: I need to clear the previous printed values in the console and need to position my cursor in [row][column]=0

```
System.out.println("Hello World");
System.out.println("Hello Country");
System.out.println("\033[0;0H"); //need to apply the escape sequence here
System.out.println("Happy:)");
```

Expected Output:

```
Happy:)
Hello Country
```

Am getting this output in this [online compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/r1rnszW1Q) but not in other compilers

Comment: no this is not duplicate of that, in my case, it is a completely different scenario. I have 7 small component installer I need to show the user something like Installing Component 1  then in the next line a loader with percentage if component 1 finished installing then I need to show Installing Component 2 by erasing the previous two printed lines in the console and it is same for the next 5 componenets. I have searched a lot but nothing works. But I can achieve this in C using the escape sequence, that's why am asking whether it is possible to achieve the same here or not.

Comment: Ahh my bad sorry =)

Comment: If you want to know how to clear the console; see @Steephen's link.  If you want to output an arbitrary control character, use an octal escape (e.g. `\033`) or a Unicode escape (e.g. `\u001B`) in the character or string literal.

Answer (score -1):

To get next line its just necesary add "\n":

```
System.out.println("\nHello World");
System.out.println("\nHello Country");
System.out.println("\nEsc[2J"); //need to apply the escape sequence here
System.out.println("\nHappy:)");
```

Comment: 1) The question is not about newlines.  It is about how to output an ESC control code.  2) The `println` call adds an end-of-line at the end of the string, so adding another is wrong.  3) Outputting a `\n` is incorrect on Windows and on Mac OSX.  On those platforms, the end-of-line sequences are different.